# Form_for editing resource without all attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, updates

I have a form_for established to edit a resource (here it is a user). In the model, it is specified that some attributes cannot be blank (e.g. password). I have a second form to edit this user as an admin. This form does not require the user password but can be filled to change this user's password. The problem is that the validation fails cause no password is specified (Validation fail: Password cannot be blank).

I'd like to know if there is a way to edit the resource this way, without deleting the password field from parameters when it's blank.

```
@user.update!(user_params)
```

Comment: You can add custom validation to tackle this issue. Add custom validation to validate the password. In case of user validate presence and in case of admin don't need to validate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like a param deletetion.  In your update method before the save do something like.

```
if params["user"].has_key? "password"
  if params["user"]["password"].empty? and user_is_admin?
    params["user"].delete("password")
  end
end
```

Replace `user_is_admin?` with your own admin checking method.

Comment: Yeah that's what I finally did. :)